Client Credentials Flow
I am trying to add a new parameter to the token request.
The goal is to find a workaround to add the user email to the requested token.
 var tokenResponse = await client.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
 {
     Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,
     ClientId = "client",
     ClientSecret = "secret",
     Scope = "api1",
     Parameters = { { "user_email", userEmail } }
 });

`
But I don't know exactly where to retrieve it from the other server.
I have tried:
public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
{
    try
    {
        if (context.Client.ClientId == "client" && context.Caller == "ClientCredentials")
        {
            var userEmail = context.ValidatedRequest.Raw.Get("user_email");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userEmail))
            {
                context.IssuedClaims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, userEmail));
            }
            return;
        }

        //Rest of the profile service 

